# Merging lists in scala

Tags: scala

I have to merge these two lists together in a way that results in the 3rd list. I'm not super familiar with Scala that much but I am always interested in learning.

`val variable = List("a", "b", "c") | val number = List("1", "2", "3")`

When merged and printing each value after, it should result in an output like this

`a is equal to 1`
`b is equal to 2`
`c is equal to 3`

with a list that is now equal to

`List("a is equal to 1", "b is equal to 2", "c is equal to 3")`

Please help me out

Comment: You could use `zip` and then iterate over the tuples to print out your results - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala_collections/scala_collections_zip.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip` and `map` would work,

```
variable.zip(number).map {case (str, int) => s"$str is equal to $int"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativly, you could use [`for-comprehensions`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html)

```scala
Welcome to Scala 3.1.1 (17, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
                                                                                                          
scala> val variable = List("a", "b", "c")
val variable: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
                                                                                                          
scala> val number = List("1", "2", "3")
val number: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
                                                                                                          
scala> for {
     |   str <- variable
     |   n <- number
     | } yield s"$str is equal to $n"
val res0: List[String] = List(a is equal to 1, a is equal to 2, a is equal to 3, b is equal to 1, b is equal to 2, b is equal to 3, c is equal to 1, c is equal to 2, c is equal to 3)
```